# Can I use a child's primary key as the parent's primary key in Realm.IO?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

For example:

```
class User: Object {
  dynamic var name: String = "Thor"
  dynamic var profile: Profile?
}

class Profile: Object {
  dynamic var id: Int = 0
  override static func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "id"
  }
}
```

So, I want Realm to not create a new user when the profile is an update using the profile's `primaryKey`.

In code,

```
let json = JSON(value)
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
  let user = User(json: json)
  realm.add(user, update: true)
}
```

Since `User` does not have a `primaryKey`, it will create a new user every time. However, since `Profile` **does** have a `primaryKey`, it only creates one profile. All the users points to that same one profile. What I would like is for the `User` to use the primary key on the `Profile` and  only create a new `User` when a new `Profile` is created.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just give User a primary key (eg. UUID)?

Comment: The API JSON response looks something like: { "name": "okysabeni", "profile": { ... } } Initially, I do have a primaryKey for User but it doesn't work because I'm taking the json response directly and just initializing the object. It will create a User duplicate.

Comment: It sounds like your User class should take the primary key from the Profile instance. Meaning in your `init(json:)` when you have loaded the `Profile` instance, set the user.id from profile.id (eg. using `didSet`). Also, Realm keeps the reference on the 'child' to the parent. Giving your json structure, it looks like profile should have a reference to user, rather than the other way around. Not that it makes much difference for a 1:1 relationship.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for amounts to giving the `User` class a concept of *identity*, which in Realm is represented by [primary keys](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys).

I'd recommend that you use the same primary key to represent both a `User` and their associated `Profile`. Alternatively, if these models can only exist together in a one-to-one relationship, why not just combine them?

```
class User: Object {
  dynamic var id: Int = 0
  dynamic var name: String = "Thor"

  override static func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "id"
  }
}
```

*I'm assuming you have more properties in your `Profile` model.*

Comment: I do. Well, I want to keep 1:1 parity with the response coming back from the API. The API JSON response looks something like: { "name": "okysabeni", "profile": { ... } } I don't have control over this API.

Comment: ok, then take my first suggestion of giving `User` a primary key. The same primary key value as its `Profile` makes sense to me.

Comment: So, another question, what if it's the other way around. Think something like this: { "reservations": { "trip": { .. } } }. In this case, I create a Trip:Object and I would need to use the reservations id. However, in my convenience init method, I only pass in the trip values and not the reservation values. Do I need to pass in the reservation object alongside the trip object when initializing?

Comment: Not at all, if you want `Trip` to have *identity*, then give it an `id` primary key property and pass that in your `Trip` initializer.